# how to show txt on web, by gae,google app engine,python

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine

i want to upload txt file and show this txt.

i had the code of uploading txt to gae, but how to show it???

i want to upload txt file and show this txt.

i had the code of uploading txt to gae, but how to show it???

i want to upload txt file and show this txt.

i had the code of uploading txt to gae, but how to show it???

```
    import os
    import urllib

    from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
    from google.appengine.ext import webapp
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
    from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app


    class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
            upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
            self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
            self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
            self.response.out.write("""Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>""")

            for b in blobstore.BlobInfo.all():
                self.response.out.write('<li><a href="/serve/%s' % str(b.key()) + '">' + str(b.filename) + '</a>')


   class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
        def post(self):
            upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
            blob_info = upload_files[0]
            self.redirect('/')


   class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
        def get(self, blob_key):
            blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
            if not blobstore.get(blob_key):
                self.error(404)
            else:
                self.send_blob(blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key), save_as=True)

        def main():
            application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
                  [('/', MainHandler),
                   ('/upload', UploadHandler),
                   ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler),
                  ], debug=True)
            run_wsgi_app(application)


     if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: @ShawnZhang it's your second comment i see around with asian characters :) just to let you know :) we (i, at least) can't read :P

Answer (score 1):

you should change the redirect function of your upload handler a bit, in the end you should redirect to the uploaded file:

```
self.redirect('/serve/%s/' % blob_info.key())
```

also, your servehandler (i'm not sure you can use this tho, it may be better if you created your own serve_txt function, i'll try anyway)

```
class ServeHandler(webapp.RequestHandler): 
  #we want to render a page, not a download, that's why it extends RequestHandler
  def get(self, resource):
    resource = str(urllib.unquote(resource))
    blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(resource) #this should be your file
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
    self.response.out.write(blob_info)
```

templating is completely up to you now, this should display a plain text to your page (being a txt, you may want to read it before with python using [BlobReader class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobreaderclass) then return the page correctly formatted. mine is just an example on how you should proceed)

Comment: self.redirect('/')＝＝＝＝change to＝＝＝＝＝＝＝self.redirect('/serve/%s/' % blob_info.key())    do you this mean?

Answer (score 0):

if you whant to show it in browser instead of saving - remove

> save_as=True

```
   class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
        def get(self, blob_key):
            blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
            if not blobstore.get(blob_key):
                self.error(404)
            else:
                self.send_blob(blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key))
```

Comment: self.response.out.write(u'<li><a href="/serve/%s">%s</a>[%s]</li>' % (b.key(),b.filename, blobstore.BlobReader(b.key()).read()))

Answer (score 0):

thanks －－－－－－－－－like it

```
import os
import urllib

from google.appengine.ext import blobstore
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import blobstore_handlers
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url('/upload')
        self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.out.write('<form action="%s" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">' % upload_url)
        self.response.out.write("""Upload File: <input type="file" name="file"><br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> </form></body></html>""")

        for b in blobstore.BlobInfo.all():
            #self.response.out.write('<li><a href="/serve/%s' % str(b.key()) + '">' + str(b.filename) + '</a>')
            self.response.out.write(u'<li><a href="/serve/%s">%s</a>[%s]</li>' % (b.key(),b.filename, blobstore.BlobReader(b.key()).read())) 

class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        upload_files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = upload_files[0]
        self.redirect('/')
       #contents = open(filename).read()

class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
        def get(self, blob_key):
            blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
            if not blobstore.get(blob_key):
                self.error(404)
            else:
                self.send_blob(blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key))

def main():
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
          [('/', MainHandler),
           ('/upload', UploadHandler),
           ('/serve/([^/]+)?', ServeHandler),
          ], debug=True)
    run_wsgi_app(application)
    print "Hello, world!1"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```